# Retrieving snapshots of game statistics

Tags: architecture, statistics, metrics

What is a good architecture for storing game statistics, so that I can retrieve snapshots of it at various moments?

Say I have a game, and the user's statistics initially are:

```
 {
 hours_played = 0,
 games_played = 0,
 no_of_times_killed = 0,
 }
```

When the user purchases something for the first time from within the game, the stats are

```
 {
 hours_played = 10,
 games_played = 2,
 no_of_times_killed = 5,
 }
```

And when he purchases something for the second time, the stats are

```
 {
 hours_played = 20,
 games_played = 4,
 no_of_times_killed = 10,
 }
```

Let me name the events as "purchase1" and "purchase2"

How do I model my statistics, so that at any point in the future, I will be able to retrieve the snapshot of the statistics at the time when "purchase1" was fired. 
Similarly for "purchase2" and any other event I will add.

Hope that made sense..

Comment: ...put them in a struct, and then store that struct somewhere until you want to read the data that you put in it before?  What exactly is the problem, here?

Answer (score 1):

Every time a memorable Event (purchase1,...) happens, save it to a list. Then, serialize it to a File.

If order doesn't matter, a Set would probably more performant.

If order doesn't matter, but you want to reference by name, look into maps/dictionaries. Your language may not nativly supply them, but implementation is fairly easy.

---

More indepth:

Create a datatype containing all relevant information.
I will call it `DataPoint` from here on.

Create a list containing `DataPoint`s.
I will call it `Events`.
*In Java you would write `List<DataPoints> Events = ...`*

Now, every time something happens, you add a new Element to the list.
    //something happens
    Events.add(new DataPoint(...));

To retrieve an element, you just get it from the list.
    Events.get(indexOfEvent)

To go over all (or at least more than one) elements of the list, use *Iterators*. As Iterators differ too much between languages, I will not show hoe to use them here.
*A lot of languages support `foreach`-loops.*